# How to set OR logic between two slicers for the attributes from same dataset?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to set `OR` logic between the two slicer filters. The two slicers are from same dataset. Below are more details:

**My source table:**

[image: This is my source test table]

**Visual with slicers:**

[image: These are the slicer filters I added for testing purposes]

My goal is, if I select any value from slicer 1 and also from slicer 2, my visual should show the results w.r.t both the select values.

For example, if I select A1 from slicer 1 and 200 from slicer 2, the result should be shown as below (Similar to SQL query (Where Column1 ='A1' or Column2=200)

**Desired result:**
[image: This is what I desire]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaINQ.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to create new tables to use for slicers.

```
Col1 = VALUES(Table1[Column1])

Col2 = VALUES(Table1[Column2])
```

Change the slicers to filter on these and now define a new measure:

```
Include = (MAX(Table1[Column1]) = SELECTEDVALUE(Col1[Column1])) +
          (MAX(Table1[Column2]) = SELECTEDVALUE(Col2[Column2]))
```

Then in the visual level filters section, filter for `[Include] > 0`:

[image: Screenshot]