# Power BI slicer OR condition

Tags: powerbi

The interaction between two slicers in Power BI gives me output with AND condition.

**Example**: If I selected the year 2020 and company ABC, the output would be all the data from company ABC in the year 2020.
But I want the two slicers to work with OR condition.

I have used this Dax

```
Include = (MAX(Table1[Column1]) = SELECTEDVALUE(Col1[Column1])) +
  (MAX(Table1[Column2]) = SELECTEDVALUE(Col2[Column2]))
```

But the problem with above Dax I have not selected anything in slicer ( ALL by default) it is showing me a blank visual. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set OR logic between two slicers for the attributes from same dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738761/how-to-set-or-logic-between-two-slicers-for-the-attributes-from-same-dataset)

Answer (score 3):

let me guess you have a table "or_slicer_main_table" with Year, Company and some other columns. Now create 2 new table where the first one will contain the distinct list of Year from table "or_slicer_main_table" and the second one will contain distinct Company list from that same table.

New custom Table 1:

```
or_slicer_year_list = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    'or_slicer_main_table',
    "YEAR", 'or_slicer_main_table'[year]
)
```

New custom Table 2:

```
or_slicer_company_list = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    'or_slicer_main_table',
    "company", 'or_slicer_main_table'[company]
)
```

> ***Do not establish any relation between those 3 tables.***

**Step-1:** Create Year slicer using the newly created "or_slicer_year_list" table.

**Step-2:** Create Company slicer using the newly created "or_slicer_company_list" table.

**Step-3:** Create these following 5 measures in your table "or_slicer_main_table"

**1.**

```
year_current_row = max('or_slicer_main_table'[year])
```

**2.**

```
year_selected_in_slicer = SELECTEDVALUE(or_slicer_year_list[YEAR])
```

**3.**

```
company_current_row = max('or_slicer_main_table'[company])
```

**4.**

```
company_selected_in_slicer = SELECTEDVALUE(or_slicer_company_list[company])
```

**5.**

```
show_hide = 
if(
    [year_selected_in_slicer] = [year_current_row] 
        || [company_selected_in_slicer] = [company_current_row], 
    1, 
    0
)
```

Now you have all instruments ready for play. Create your visual using columns from the table "or_slicer_main_table"

**Final Step:** Now just add a visual level filter for the measure "show_hide" and set value will show only when "show_hide = 1".

The final output will be something like below image-

[image]

Comment: No i dont want to consolidate two diff slicer.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @johndoe do you have single selection in the slicer? like Only 1 year and 1 Company can be selected. If yes, there is a work around probably.

Comment: Yes single selection in the slicer

Comment: Hi @johndoe, I have edited my whole answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using "IN VALUES" instead of "SELECTEDVALUE"

So your DAX should be

```
Include = (MAX(Table1[Column1]) IN VALUES (Col1[Column1])) + 
(MAX(Table1[Column2]) IN VALUES (Col2[Column2]))
```

**SELECTEDVALUE** function returns the result only if single value is selected in slicer in case of multiple selection it will return **Blank()**. Thats in the case when nothing is selected (which is similar to all selected) has multiple values in set and so **SELECTEDVALUE** fucntion will return **Blank()**. This can be handled by using **"IN VALUES"** function which can return a set of all selected values.