# How to have two columns for two slicers and output should be based on two slicers in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals, slicers

I have one table called School_Table

| StudentID | Schl code | State code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | AS |
| 2 | 101 | AS |
| 3 | 102 | AS |
| 4 | 102 | AS |
| 5 | 103 | AS |
| 6 | 104 | AS |

I want one slicer has Student ID and another Slicer has school code. If in my first slicer (Student ID) I have selected value 1,2 and second slicer (school code) as value 103,104 then I should get my output table as records student ID as 1,2,5,6.

I am new to Power BI. Can we achieve this ??

Comment: There are a number of techniques to do this. You can read about them here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-or-conditions-between-slicers-in-dax/

Comment: Why do beginners always want to change the default behavior of programs before they  even learned how to use the basic concepts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241081/power-bi-slicer-or-condition This link is somewhat similar to my requirement but I want multiple select option. But they have shown only single select option. Can you please help me from this..